# Что нужно сделать,чтобы был рандомный вывод команд без повторений в тг боте на js

Tags: javascript, telegram-bot

```
const  ran = ['first.MP4', 'second.MP4', 'three.MP4'];
if (msg.text === '/com') { 

        let rdm= ran[(Math.floor(Math.random() * ran.length))];
  
        let index = ran.indexOf(rdm);
  
        if (index > -1) {
          ran.splice(index, 1);
          bot.sendVideo(msg.from.id, rdm); 
    }
  }})
```

Comment: Одной команды из массива команд? Или всех команд но в рандомном порядке?

Comment: @Byb одной команды